# R Conditional Summing (condition within group)

Tags: r, sum, dplyr, conditional-statements

There seems to be quite a few threats about conditional summing in R using dplyr but none of those that I read through were helpful in answering the following.

I have the following dataset:

```
ID  Code  Value  AnnualChange

1   123    100       0.01
2   123    200       0.05
3   123    150       0.1
4   124    200       0.01
5   124    250       0.1
6   124    200       0.2
```

What I would like to do is to get an extra column which would give me sum of all items of a particular code which grew more than, say 2%. Additionally, I would like to have a column showing the proportion of fast growing items in each code. Hence, the result would look like this:

```
 ID  Code  Value  AnnualChange  FastGrowing   Proportion

    1   123    100       0.01        350           0.77
    2   123    200       0.05        350           0.77
    3   123    150       0.1         350           0.77
    4   124    200       0.01        450           0.69
    5   124    250       0.1         450           0.69
    6   124    200       0.2         450           0.69
```

I hope this makes sense. Apologies if this was asked somewhere else, I really took my time and didn't find anything like this.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ifelse`:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(Code) %>%
    mutate(FastestGrowing = sum(ifelse(AnnualChange >= .02, Value, 0)),
           Proportion = FastestGrowing / sum(Value))

     ID  Code Value AnnualChange FastestGrowing Proportion
  <int> <int> <int>        <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1   123   100       0.0100           350.      0.778
2     2   123   200       0.0500           350.      0.778
3     3   123   150       0.100            350.      0.778
4     4   124   200       0.0100           450.      0.692
5     5   124   250       0.100            450.      0.692
6     6   124   200       0.200            450.      0.692
```

#### data

```
dat <- read.table(text = "ID  Code  Value  AnnualChange
                  1   123    100       0.01
                  2   123    200       0.05
                  3   123    150       0.1
                  4   124    200       0.01
                  5   124    250       0.1
                  6   124    200       0.2", header = TRUE)
```